# What are helpful optimizations in R for big data sets?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I built a script that works great with small data sets (<1 M rows) and performs very poorly with large datasets. I've heard of data table as being more performant than tibbles. I'm interested to know about other speed optimizations in addition to learn about data tables.

I'll share a couple of commands in the script for examples. In each of the examples, the datasets are 10 to 15 million rows and 10 to 15 columns.

1. Getting the lowest date for a dataframe grouped by nine variables

```
      dataframe %>% 
      group_by(key_a, key_b, key_c,
               key_d, key_e, key_f,
               key_g, key_h, key_i) %>%
      summarize(min_date = min(date)) %>% 
      ungroup()
```

2. Doing a left join on two dataframes to add an additional column

```
      merge(dataframe, 
          dataframe_two, 
          by = c("key_a", "key_b", "key_c",
               "key_d", "key_e", "key_f",
               "key_g", "key_h", "key_i"),
          all.x = T) %>% 
      as_tibble()
```

3. Joining two dataframes on the [closest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770101/join-with-fuzzy-matching-by-date-in-r)

```
      dataframe %>%
      left_join(dataframe_two, 
                  by = "key_a") %>%
      group_by(key_a, date.x) %>%
      summarise(key_z = key_z[which.min(abs(date.x - date.y))]) %>%
      arrange(date.x) %>%
      rename(day = date.x)
```

What best practices can I apply and, in particular, what can I do to make these types of functions optimized for large datasets?

--

This is an example dataset

```
set.seed(1010)
library("conflicted")
conflict_prefer("days", "lubridate")
bigint <- rep(
  sample(1238794320934:19082323109, 1*10^7)
)

key_a <-
  rep(c("green", "blue", "orange"), 1*10^7/2)

key_b <-
  rep(c("yellow", "purple", "red"), 1*10^7/2)

key_c <-
  rep(c("hazel", "pink", "lilac"), 1*10^7/2)

key_d <-
  rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 1*10^7/2)

key_e <-
  rep(c("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), 1*10^7/5)

key_f <-
  rep(c("Z", "M", "Q", "T", "X", "B"), 1*10^7/5)

key_g <-
  rep(c("Z", "M", "Q", "T", "X", "B"), 1*10^7/5)

key_h <-
  rep(c("tree", "plant", "animal", "forest"), 1*10^7/3)

key_i <-
  rep(c("up", "up", "left", "left", "right", "right"), 1*10^7/5)

sequence <- 
  seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-01"), by = "1 day")

date_sequence <-
  rep(sequence, 1*10^7/(length(sequence) - 1))

dataframe <-
  data.frame(
    bigint,
    date = date_sequence[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_a = key_a[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_b = key_b[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_c = key_c[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_d = key_d[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_e = key_e[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_f = key_f[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_g = key_g[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_h = key_h[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_i = key_i[1:(1*10^7)]
  )

dataframe_two <-
  dataframe %>%
      mutate(date_sequence = ymd(date_sequence) + days(1))

sequence_sixdays <-
  seq(ymd("2010-01-01"), ymd("2020-01-01"), by = "6 days")

date_sequence <-
  rep(sequence_sixdays, 3*10^6/(length(sequence_sixdays) - 1))

key_z <-
  sample(1:10000000, 3*10^6)

dataframe_three <-
  data.frame(
    key_a = sample(key_a, 3*10^6),
    date = date_sequence[1:(3*10^6)],
    key_z = key_z[1:(3*10^6)]
  )
```

Comment: data.table could be [well suited to your needs](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping). Could you supply a script to create fake data to test this with `microbenchmark`?

Comment: Check out the `tidyft::parse_fst` where you read fst file.

Comment: Have you look at `dtplyr`? (`The goal of dtplyr is to allow you to write dplyr code that is automatically translated to the equivalent, but usually much faster, data.table code.`)

Comment: From the tidyverse page https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/, it appears that dtplyr (though very cool) is slower than data table (`Why is dtplyr slower than data.table?`)

Comment: Yes, but the difference seems to be not so big: https://iyarlin.github.io/2020/05/26/dtplyr_benchmarks/ As this link explains, you can do it even faster by imposing `dataframe` to be a `data.table`

Comment: This list by Dirk Eddelbuettel has lots of tools for working with large datasets https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: You should including loading `lubridate` package in your example, it uses `ymd` function. Question in general could be improved to be fully reproducible, that would be useful for answers to provide working code.

Comment: Additionally task 1 ( lowest date) doesn't work with your dataframe - hard to benchmark this this way to suggest a faster solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What best practices can I apply and, in particular, what can I do to make these types of functions optimized for large datasets?

use `data.table` package

```r
library(data.table)
d1 = as.data.table(dataframe)
d2 = as.data.table(dataframe_two)
```

---

#### 1

grouping by many columns is something that data.table is excellent at
see barchart at the very bottom of the second plot for comparison against dplyr spark and others for exactly this kind of grouping
https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark

```r
by_cols = paste("key", c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), sep="_")
a1 = d1[, .(min_date = min(date_sequence)), by=by_cols]
```

note I changed `date` to `date_sequence`, I think you meant that as a column name

#### 2

it is unclear on what fields you want to merge tables, dataframe_two does not have specified fields so the query is invalid
please clarify

#### 3

data.table has very useful type of join called rolling join, which does exactly what you need

```r
a3 = d2[d1, on=c("key_a","date_sequence"), roll="nearest"]
# Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || #!anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
#  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached #physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for #duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in #x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for #each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search #for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and #data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

It results an error. Error is in fact very useful. On your real data it may work perfectly fine, as the reason behind the error (cardinality of matching rows) may be related to process of generating sample data. It is very tricky to have good dummy data for joining.
If you are getting the same error on your real data you may want to review design of that query as it attempts to make row explosion by doing many-to-many join. Even after already considering only single `date_sequence` identity (taking `roll` into account). I don't see this kind of question to be valid for that data (cadrinalities of join fields strictly speaking). You may want to introduce data quality checks layer in your workflow to ensure there are no duplicates on `key_a` and `date_sequence` combined.

Comment: This is a great article about how rolling joins work https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/r-data-table-rolling-joins/

Comment: point 2 still needs clarification. Your `merge` call specify columns to join on that don't exist in both tables which is an invalid usage. If I would know on which columns you want to merge those tables I could try to provide ready-to-use code.

Comment: Can you also mention that values of setting keys in joins with data tables?

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to reproduce your code and getting `dataframe_two <-
+   dataframe %>%
+       mutate(date_sequence = date_sequence + days(1))
✖ Input `date_sequence` can't be recycled to size 10000000.
ℹ Input `date_sequence` is `date_sequence + days(1)`.
ℹ Input `date_sequence` must be size 10000000 or 1, not 10001914.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: I'll use dput maybe that'll be easier. Can you please try again with library(conflicted) and conflict_prefer("days", "lubridate"). data tables and lubridate both have a function called `days` and can you wrap date_sequence with ymd(). I'll update the description

Comment: does not help much: `dataframe_two <- mutate(dataframe, date_sequence = lubridate::ymd(date_sequence) + lubridate::days(1))` gives the same error.

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide example code using base R

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @jangorecki's answer.

Data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(conflicted)
library(data.table)

dataframe = data.frame(bigint,
    date_sequence = date_sequence[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_a = key_a[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_b = key_b[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_c = key_c[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_d = key_d[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_e = key_e[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_f = key_f[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_g = key_g[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_h = key_h[1:(1*10^7)],
    key_i = key_i[1:(1*10^7)])

dataframe_two = dataframe %>% mutate(date_sequence1 = ymd(date_sequence) + days(1))

dataframe_two$date_sequence = NULL
```

Benchmarks:

### 1.

dplyr result of 2 runs: 2.2639 secs; 2.2205 secs

```
st = Sys.time()
a1 = dataframe %>% 
  group_by(key_a, key_b, key_c,
           key_d, key_e, key_f,
           key_g, key_h, key_i) %>%
  summarize(min_date = min(date_sequence)) %>% ungroup()
Sys.time() - st
```

data.table results: 1.0987 secs; 0.9825 secs

```
setDT(dataframe)
by_cols = paste("key", c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), sep="_")
st = Sys.time()
a2 = dataframe[, .(min_date = min(date_sequence)), by=by_cols]
Sys.time() - st
```

### 2.

dplyr

```
setDF(dataframe)
st = Sys.time()
df3 = merge(dataframe, 
      dataframe_two, 
      by = c("key_a", "key_b", "key_c",
             "key_d", "key_e", "key_f",
             "key_g", "key_h", "key_i"),
      all.x = T) %>% as_tibble()
Sys.time() - st
# Error in merge.data.frame(dataframe, dataframe_two, by = c("key_a", "key_b",  : 
#  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

data.table

```
setDT(dataframe)
setDT(dataframe_two)
st = Sys.time()
df3 = merge(dataframe, 
            dataframe_two, 
            by = c("key_a", "key_b", "key_c",
                   "key_d", "key_e", "key_f",
                   "key_g", "key_h", "key_i"),
            all.x = T)
Sys.time() - st
# Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  # : 
#  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). 
# Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which 
# join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to 
# run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for 
# this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker 
# for advice.
```

This error is helpful and running the following:

```
uniqueN(dataframe_two, by = c("key_a", "key_b", "key_c",
                                    "key_d", "key_e", "key_f",
                                    "key_g", "key_h", "key_i"))
```

gives

```
12
```

When I am working with datasets containing about 10 million rows and 15 columns, I convert strings to factors before merging and have seen performance gains from approx. 30 secs to 10 secs for an inner join. To my surprise, setkey() was not as effective as converting strings to factors in that particular case.

**EDIT:** Reproducible example of data.table merge in 3 flavours (on character column, setkey, strings to factors)

Create tables:

```
x = 1e6
ids = x:(2*x-1)
chrs = rep(LETTERS[1:10], x)
quant_1 = sample(ids, x, replace = T)
quant_2 = sample(ids, x, replace = T)

ids_c = paste0(chrs, as.character(ids))

dt1 = data.table(unique(ids_c), quant_1)
dt2 = data.table(unique(ids_c), quant_2)
```

(i) on character column

```
system.time({result_chr = merge(dt1, dt2, by = 'V1')})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.66    5.18   18.64
```

(ii) using setkey

```
system.time(setkey(dt1, V1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.37    1.55    5.66 
system.time(setkey(dt2, V1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.42    1.67    5.85  
system.time({result_setkey = merge(dt1, dt2, by = 'V1')})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.17    0.00    0.16
```

(iii) strings to factors

```
dt3 = data.table(unique(ids_c), quant_1)
dt4 = data.table(unique(ids_c), quant_2)

system.time({dt3[, V1 := as.factor(V1)]})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.16    0.00    8.20 
system.time({dt4[, V1 := as.factor(V1)]})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.04    0.00    8.06 
system.time({result_fac = merge(dt3, dt4, by = 'V1')})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.32    0.01    0.28
```

In this case, setkey is overall the fastest with total 11.67 seconds. However, if data is ingested with strings to factors as true then no need to use setkey.

**Example 2:** In case your data comes in one file with rows separated by an attribute, for example date, and you need to separate them first, then do a join.

Data:

```
dt5 = data.table(date = '202009', id = unique(ids_c), quant = quant_1)
dt6 = data.table(date = '202010', id = unique(ids_c), quant = quant_2)
# Original data comes combined
dt = rbindlist(list(dt5, dt6))
```

(i) setkey

```
system.time(setkey(dt, id))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  5.78    3.39   10.78 
dt5 = dt[date == '202009']
dt6 = dt[date == '202010']
system.time({result_setkey = merge(dt5, dt6, by = 'id')})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.17    0.00    0.17
```

(ii) strings as factors

```
dt5 = data.table(date = '202009', id = unique(ids_c), quant = quant_1)
dt6 = data.table(date = '202010', id = unique(ids_c), quant = quant_2)
dt = rbindlist(list(dt5, dt6))
system.time({dt[, id := as.factor(id)]})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.17    0.00    8.20  
dt5 = dt[date == '202009']
dt6 = dt[date == '202010']
system.time({result_fac = merge(dt5, dt6, by = 'id')})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.34    0.00    0.33
```

In this case, strings to factors is faster at 8.53 seconds vs 10.95. However, when shuffling the keys before creating the tables `ids_c = sample(ids_c, replace = F)`, setkey performs 2x faster.

Also, note that not every function in data.table is faster than combination of base functions. For example:

```
# data.table    
system.time(uniqueN(ids_c))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.63    4.21   16.88 

# base R
system.time(length(unique(ids_c)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.78    0.08    0.94
```

Important to note that uniqueN() consumes 4x less memory, so would be better to use if RAM size is a constraint. I've used profvis package for this flame graph (from a different run than above):
[image: flame graph]

Finally, if working with datasets larger than RAM, have a look at [disk.frame](https://diskframe.com/).

Answer (score 3):

By default, R works with data in memory. When your data gets significantly larger R can throw out-of-memory errors, or depending on your setup use the pagefile ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876328/forcing-r-and-rstudio-to-use-the-virtual-memory-on-windows)) but the pagefiles is slow as it involves reading and writing to disk.

### 1. batching

From just a computation perspective, you may find improvements by batching your processing. Your examples include summarising the dataset down, so presumably your summarised dataset is much smaller than your input (if not, it would be worth considering other approaches to producing the same final dataset). This means that you can batch by your grouping variables.

I often do this by taking modulo of a numeric index:

```r
num_batches = 50
output = list()

for(i in 0:(num_batches-1)){
  subset = df %>% filter(numeric_key %% num_batches == i)

  this_summary = subset %>%
    group_by(numeric_key, other_keys) %>%
    summarise(result = min(col)

  output[[i]] = this_summary
}
final_output = bind_rows(output)
```

You can develop a similar approach for text-based keys.

### 2. reduce data size

Storing text requires more memory than storing numeric data. An easy option here is to replace strings with numeric codes, or store strings as factors. This will use less memory, and hence the computer has less information to read when grouping/joining.

Note that depending on your version of R, `stringsAsFactors` may default to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So probably best to set it explicitly. ([discussed here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html))

### 3. move to disk

Beyond some size it is worth having data on disk and letting R manage reading to and from disk. This is part of the idea behind several existing R packages including [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf), [ff and ffbase](https://rpubs.com/demydd/235941), and a host of [parallelisation packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Beyond just depending on R, you can push tasks to a database. While a database will never perform as quickly as in-memory data, they are designed for handling large quantities of data. PostgreSQL is free and open source ([getting started guide here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-started-with-postgresql-in-r/)), and you can run this on the same machine as R - it does not have to be a dedicated server. R also has a package specifically for PostgreSQL ([RPostgreSQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html)). There are also several other packages designed for working with databases including dbplyr, DBI, RODBC if you want other options for interacting with databases.

While there is some overhead setting up a database, dplyr and dbplyr will translate your R code into SQL for you, so you don't have to learn a new language. The downside is that you are limited to core dplyr commands as translations from R to SQL are only defined for the standard procedures.

Comment: Can I spin up the PostgreSQL db from within my R instance or terminal?

Comment: R can pass commands to the cmd prompt, and (almost) anything you can do with a mouse & keyboard interactively you could do from the terminal. So if you're very determined then I am sure you'd find a way. But I don't have a way to do this, and the tutorials I've found online involve some setup outside of R. Note that once a database is setup on the computer, you can access it and load data into it from within R.

Comment: For your point 2, R uses [a global string pool](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#character-vectors) so storing strings as factors shouldn't bring any additional benefit.

Comment: @Alexlok makes a good point if working within R. If reading/writing to disk or a database then this still is worth considering.

Comment: Adding to @Alexlok  factors are in general memory inefficient in `R` when compared to character vectors. One of the main points why `stringAsFactors` was changed to default to `FALSE` in ´R-4.0.0`.

Comment: factors might be more efficient if one handles them properly, the change in R was dictated by user convenience, not by efficiency. Agree with Alexlok about global cache, so you will not save memory by "no repeating character entries" but still factor is int (4bit) and char is 8bit, so low level code can use it, and in data.table in many places it does. Unless it is high cardinality variable, then it still keep most of entries in attributes anyway.